# How to split dataframe lines into columns in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I converted from a an excel file, it contains a lot of data and it looks something like this. Everything is on the same column.

*Edit : This is the dataframe (and the excel file looks the same) :*

```
  # Daily air quality and meteorological measurementa for majors world-wide cities in 2020
0  # By using this data you agree with the terms ...                                      
1  # For more information check: https://aqicn.or...                                      
2  # Data-Set Generated on 2020-05-06T08:48:59+01:00                                      
3  Date,Country,City,Specie,count,min,max,median,...                                      
4  2020-02-23,CR,San JosÃ©,pm25,20,13.0,53.0,25.0...                                      
5  2020-04-04,CR,San JosÃ©,pm25,23,17.0,57.0,38.0...
```

It's a dataframe containing a lot of data about air quality. I would like to split the lines into different columns to make the values correspond to each other: the data, the country, city etc
How can I do this ?

Thank you very much

Comment: So, is this the dataframe or the excel file??

Comment: This is a csv file, use `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Like @Erfan mentioned this looks like a **csv** file, to exclude the header use `skiprows`  parameter of `pd.read_csv` and same applies to `pd.read_excel` if it's excel file.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it's the dataframe. I used pd.read_excel

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few assumptions so this might need some minor tweaking, but this should more or less work:

```
# drop comment rows
df = df[~df[0].str.startswith('#')]

# split column into multiple columns
df[0].str.split(',',  expand=True)

# update header
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because it doesn't take in account the commented lines.
You should probably add the `comment='#'` parameter to the `pd.read_csv(...)` when you load your file.